# Lines in if statement printing even when triggering another statement. Python 3.0

Tags: python-3.x

```
print("Example intro.")

answer = input("Write one, two, three, four or five (caps or no caps.)").lower().strip()

if answer == "one" or "One" or "ONE":
    print("1")                      
    
if answer == "two" or "Two" or "TWO":
   print("2")

if answer == "three" or "Three" or "THREE":
    print("3")

if answer ==  "four" or "Four" or "FOUR":
    print ("4")

if answer == "five" or "Five" or "FIVE":
    print ("5")
```

When you run the code it shows 1
2
3
4
5
as the result for all of the answers. Please tell me howe to fix this because Friday 14th October 2022 (GMT) is my deadline.

(This isn't the full script BTW)

Comment: To solve it yourself simplify things: `if answer == "one":`. By the way, that would be sufficient because of `lower`. You are missing `(answer = ...) or ((answer = ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

In python any non-zero value evaluates to true.

```
# the "One" by itself evaluates to true

if answer == "one" or "One" or "ONE":
    print("1")
```

needs to be rewritten as

```
if (answer == "one") or (answer == "One") or (answer == "ONE"):
    print("1")
```